# Add rectangle and text in an existing PDF. The text is upside down

Tags: python, pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqPJZ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhzvQ.png)I'm trying to create a rectangle box and add text in an existing PDF using python. The intension is to overlap a sentence in PDF with the new one. I was able to create the rectangle and the text, but the text is inverted. How can I make it right side up?

```
import pandas as pd
import fitz

doc = fitz.open("sample.pdf")
page = doc[0]

df = pd.read_excel("Book2.xlsx")
text = str(df.iloc[0, 0]) 

rect = fitz.Rect(60, 600, 0, 150) [::-1]
fill_color = (0, 0, 1)

page.draw_rect(rect, fill=fill_color, width=0)

hardcore_text = "WARNING: This document contains confidential 
information!"
hardcore_textbox = page.insert_textbox(rect, hardcore_text, 
fontsize=12, fontname="Helvetica", align=1)

text_rect = fitz.Rect(500, -50, 600, 50) 
textbox = page.insert_textbox(text_rect, text, fontsize=24, 
fontname="Helvetica", align=2, rotate=180)

doc.save("output3.pdf")
```

Comment: Have you tried not rotating it 180 degrees as you seem to be doin in the next to last line of code. BTW: code is much easier to read if it is in a code block.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My apologies, I'm new here. Yes, I've tried removing the "rotate" and the text becomes mirrored. I've attached a screenshot of the output.

Comment: And if you put 0 or -180?

Comment: Check the viewing rotation of the original PDF pages i.e the /Rotate entry in its pages. If it turns out to be non-zero, you can pre-process the file with `cpdf -upright in.pdf -o out.pdf` to normalize things.

Comment: If I add 0, it turns the text but it's still upside down. I've added screenshots of both "0" & "180"

Comment: The viewing rotation is correct in my PDF. I tried using UTF-8, which arranged the words in the right way but each alphabet are reversed.